# SAWarning: Evaluating non-mapped column expression

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have been testing sqlalchemy for a few days and have some problems using the update method in ORM mode.

What I basically want to do is to update a table from the result of a subquery performed on a second table.

Here is a simplified example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Float, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://urldb', echo=True)
session = Session(engine)

class User1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user1'
    index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value1 = Column(Float)
    value2 = Column(Boolean)


class User2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user2'
    index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value1 = Column(Float)
    value2 = Column(Boolean)

try:
    User1.__table__.drop(engine)
    User2.__table__.drop(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
except:
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


user1 = User1(value1=12, value2=True)
user2 = User1(value1=15, value2=True)
user3 = User1(value1=7, value2=True)
user4 = User2(value1=12, value2=True)
user5 = User2(value1=15, value2=False)

session.add(user1)
session.add(user2)
session.add(user3)
session.add(user4)
session.add(user5)

session.flush()
session.commit()

stmt = session.query(User2).filter(User2.value1 > 12).subquery()

session.query(User1).filter(User1.value1 == stmt.c.value1).update({User1.value2 : stmt.c.value2})
session.commit()
```

I expect `value2` from `user2` to be updated to `False`, which that code does correctly. However, I get the following warning message. As far as I understand, update would expect some ORM like expression instead of stmt.c. But I do not see how to convert my stmt object into an ORM one (tried aliased to User1 but failed, I understood why afterwards...).

Any idea to circumvent that warning msg? Thanks in advance!

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/evaluator.py:71: SAWarning: Evaluating non-mapped column expression '%(4357770376 anon)s.value1' onto ORM instances; this is a deprecated use case.  Please make use of the actual mapped columns in ORM-evaluated UPDATE / DELETE expressions.
>     "UPDATE / DELETE expressions." % clause)
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/evaluator.py:71: SAWarning: Evaluating non-mapped column expression '%(4357770376 anon)s.value2' onto ORM instances; this is a deprecated use case.  Please make use of the actual mapped columns in ORM-evaluated UPDATE / DELETE expressions.
>     "UPDATE / DELETE expressions." % clause)

Answer (score 1):

The subquery declaration is not necessary. You can directly `update from` on version 1.4:

```py
from sqlalchemy import update

session.execute(
    update(User1).values(
        value2=User2.value2
    )
    .where(User1.value1==User2.value1, User2.value1 > 12)
    .execution_options(synchronize_session="fetch") # won't work with 'evaluate'
)
session.commit()
# UPDATE user1 SET value2=(SELECT user2.value2 
# FROM user2 
# WHERE user1.value1 = user2.value1) WHERE user1.value1 > %(value1_1)s 
# RETURNING user1.index
```

You have to set the `execution_options` to not raise an error.

Another option involves a correlated subquery for the values only:

```py
from sqlalchemy import select, update

session.execute(
    update(User1).values(
        value2=select(User2.value2).\
                where(User1.value1 == User2.value1).\
                scalar_subquery()
    )
    .where(User1.value1 > 12)
)
session.commit()
# UPDATE user1 SET value2=user2.value2 
# FROM user2 WHERE user1.value1 = user2.value1 AND user2.value1 >= %(value1_1)s 
# RETURNING user1.index
```

But then the `update where` condition has to be applied on `User1`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following solution: 1. perform a `session.query(stmt).all()`, 2. build a `mydict` dictionnary based on result of 1., 3. create a new `User1` instance with `new_user = User1(**mydict)`, 4. Perform the `update` using `new_user` instead of `stmt.c`. No more SAWarning msg.
Anyone having a more elegant/efficient solution?

Comment: Instead of querying the subquery, `session.query(User2).filter(User2.value1 > 12).all()` would return `User2` instances directly avoiding the burden to have intermediate dicts.